# Prisma: use count inside a mutation resolver

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, prisma-graphql

I have a mutation `createPet` and want it to throw an error if the user already has 5 pets created. 
I was thinking that something like this will work but it doesn't:

```
  const petsCount = await db.pets({
    where: { owner: user.id },
  }).count();
```

I also didn't find anything in the docs

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a count, you can use Aggregations:

```
const petsCount = await prisma
  .petsConnection({where: {owner: user.id}})
  .aggregate()
  .count()
```

Source: [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#aggregations)